# Trying to use .gitignore file to ignore .log files

Tags: git, github, latex, gitignore

I am writing in LaTeX and when you save a file in .tex it generate files that I don't want git to track.

The .tex file will make a .log, .aux, .synctex.gz file. I have successfully ignored the .aux and the .synctex.gz with this:

```
.DS_Store
*.log
*.aux
*.synctex.gz
```

But the log file is still tracked. When I do a git add * it says:

```
modified:   assets/latex/array/array.log
modified:   assets/latex/array/array.pdf
modified:   assets/latex/template.log
modified:   assets/latex/template.pdf
modified:   assets/latex/template.tex
```

Also, I have tried this:

```
.DS_Store
assets/latex/array/array.aux
assets/latex/array/array.log
assets/latex/array/array.synctex.gz

assets/latex/else/else.aux
assets/latex/else/else.log
assets/latex/else/else.synctex.gz

assets/latex/elseif/elseif.aux
assets/latex/elseif/elseif.log
assets/latex/elseif/elseif.synctex.gz

assets/latex/for-loop/forloop.aux
assets/latex/for-loop/forloop.log
assets/latex/for-loop/forloop.synctex.gz

assets/latex/if/if.aux
assets/latex/if/if.log
assets/latex/if/if.synctex.gz

assets/latex/switch/switch.aux
assets/latex/switch/switch.log
assets/latex/switch/switch.synctex.gz

assets/latex/var/var.aux
assets/latex/var/var.log
assets/latex/var/var.synctex.gz

assets/latex/template.aux
assets/latex/template.log
assets/latex/template.synctex.gz
```

This also doesn't work.

Comment: You're already tracking some of the `.log` files, hence why it says "Modified". Look at `git rm --cached` to untrack them.

Comment: Add *.log to your .gitignore file (no need to specify every log file). Then `git rm --cached assets/latex/*/*.log`. Then add and commit.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `**/*.log`, where the double-star means to apply it recursively, so it will match every subdirectory.

Comment: You don't need that.  `*.log` applies to everything in reach.